# Invert icon color when background color changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicolor

I have a view with Icon inside it the icon border is blue ,

when start filling the view with blue color ,and the filling start over the icon i want to invert the icon border color to white ? only the part covered by blu color ?

[image]

Comment: Can't understand.....!!! What you are asking ?

Comment: @KetanParmar update my question

Comment: @KetanParmar check the image , you can see that the border color change when it come to blue background

Comment: @KetanParmar and ? can you help ?

Comment: I think it is not possible according to my knowledge!!! Because how you change color of portion of image!!

Comment: @KetanParmar maybe work a round ? like two image and cropping ?

Comment: The best way is to use gif. It's not possible to do it in the UIkit as far as I know. Get the images, and animte them.

Comment: @Omarj : check my answer for work around!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as work around something like,

Add multiple images with 0% blue to 100% blue.

Then you can set images with respect to color.

For example, if you have 10 image then set it's name like : image1,image2,image3 etc.

then first set image1 which is totally white. then set image2 that have some blue portion.

Then set image3 that have more blue portion.

You can called it `gif` also somehow!!!!